# Display custom confirmation modal when leaving form in Native Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a custom confirmation modal using Bootstrap before users navigate away from a form they have filled out. This modal should be triggered when they attempt to click on another menu, refresh the page, or use the browser's back button. The purpose is to alert users about potential loss of unsaved data and provide them with the option to confirm or cancel the navigation action.

I attempted to use the 'beforeunload' event in JavaScript to implement a custom confirmation modal before users navigate away from a page with a filled-out form.

However, I encountered an issue where the event did not wait for user confirmation in the modal and proceeded to unload the page.

To address this, I experimented with using 'e.preventDefault()' to prevent the default behavior, but this resulted in the display of the default JavaScript alert. I aim to avoid showing this default alert and, instead, use my custom modal for a more user-friendly experience.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function (e) {
        // check if form is already filled
        const roleNameInput = document.getElementById('role_name');
        const isRoleNameEmpty = roleNameInput.value.trim() === '';

        const isAnyCheckboxUnchecked = !Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-role-input')).some(el => el.checked);

        if (!isRoleNameEmpty || !isAnyCheckboxUnchecked) {
            const discardConfirmModalEl = document.getElementById('discardConfirmation');

            const modal = new Modal(discardConfirmModalEl);
            modal.show();

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Using `onbeforeunload` with the builtin dialog is the only way to block navigation

Comment: You generally can't prevent a user from navigating away from your page. While that doesn't seem to be your main intent, it is still an important requirement for what you're trying to do. (Note that the majority of sites that make a huge effort to get close to being able to do something like this are mostly the shadier porn sites.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't custom Modal when user refresh or click back button,but only a default confirm box you can show like this

```js
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.returnValue = ""
      });
```